# Best way to check HTTP 1.1 request has a body or not

Tags: http, request, http-headers, content-length

Suggest an efficient way to check the http/1.1 request has a body or not. Can check it using content-length header. But some requests are not having content-length header. Are there any means without using content-length header to determine it

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP specification has a whole section on how to correctly determine the presence and size of a request body. See RFC 7230, Section 3.3 (https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#message.body)